# SQL 30 day active user query

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table of users and how many events they fired on a given date:

| DATE | USERID | EVENTS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-27 | 1 | 5 |
| 2021-07-25 | 1 | 7 |
| 2021-07-23 | 2 | 3 |
| 2021-07-20 | 3 | 9 |
| 2021-06-22 | 1 | 9 |
| 2021-05-05 | 1 | 4 |
| 2021-05-05 | 2 | 2 |
| 2021-05-05 | 3 | 6 |
| 2021-05-05 | 4 | 8 |
| 2021-05-05 | 5 | 1 |

I want to create a table showing number of active users for each date with active user being defined as someone who has fired an event on the given date or in any of the preceding 30 days.

| DATE | ACTIVE_USERS |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-08-27 | 1 |
| 2021-07-25 | 3 |
| 2021-07-23 | 2 |
| 2021-07-20 | 2 |
| 2021-06-22 | 1 |
| 2021-05-05 | 5 |

I tried the following query which returned only the users who were active on the specified date:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT USERID), DATE
FROM table
WHERE DATE >= (CURRENT_DATE() - interval '30 days')
GROUP BY 2 ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

I also tried using a window function with rows between but seems to end up getting the same result:

```
SELECT
    DATE,
    SUM(ACTIVE_USERS) AS ACTIVE_USERS
FROM
(
SELECT
    DATE,
    CASE
        WHEN SUM(EVENTS) OVER (PARTITION BY USERID ORDER BY DATE ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) >= 1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS ACTIVE_USERS
FROM table
)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

I'm using SQL:ANSI on Snowflake. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also specify the expected result - [mcve].

Comment: Ah, my bad. I'll edit the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky to do as window functions -- because `count(distinct)` is not permitted.  You can use a self-join:

```
select t1.date, count(distinct t2.userid)
from table t join
     table t2
     on t2.date <= t.date and
        t2.date > t.date - interval '30 day'
group by t1.date;
```

However, that can be expensive.  One solution is to "unpivot" the data.  That is, do an incremental count per user of going "in" and "out" of active states and then do a cumulative sum:

```
with d as (  -- calculate the dates with "ins" and "outs"
      select user, date, +1 as inc
      from table
      union all
      select user, date + interval '30 day', -1 as inc
      from table
     ),
     d2 as (  -- accumulate to get the net actives per day
      select date, user, sum(inc) as change_on_day,
             sum(sum(inc)) over (partition by user order by date) as running_inc
      from d
      group by date, user
     ),
     d3 as (  -- summarize into active periods
      select user, min(date) as start_date, max(date) as end_date
      from (select d2.*,
                   sum(case when running_inc = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by user order by date) as active_period
            from d2
           ) d2
      where running_inc > 0
      group by user
     )
select d.date, count(d3.user)
from (select distinct date from table) d left join
     d3
     on d.date >= start_date and d.date < end_date
group by d.date;
```

Comment: Thank you! The first solution gives exactly the output I'm looking for. The second returns the error: "SQL compilation error: [IFF(D2.RUNNING_INC = 0, 1, 0)] is not a valid group by expression". I believe it's referring to d2

Comment: @Kabobz . . . No.  That was in `d3`.  It looks like a line of code got deleted.  I fixed the answer.

Comment: thanks, it works now. For some reason solution 2 gives the same number of active users as solution 1 for today but a couple of thousand more per day compared to solution 1 for any previous day. Any idea what that could be about?

Comment: @Kabobz . . . It might be including the end date.  Use `interval 29 day` instead.

Comment: strangely solution 2 still has more active users on a given day compared to solution 1

Comment: @Kabobz . . . I just added a `where` clause that is needed.  I forgot to filter out the time periods where a user is not active!